# Extend key validity of a PGP key (public and secret) based on the keyId using Bouncy Castle Open PGP Java APIs

Tags: java, bouncycastle, gnupg, pgp, openpgp

Need a help on extending the validity/expiry of a PGP secret/public key based on the associated keyId. We are able to extend the key validity but its resulting in a altogether new keyId which we don't want, any code snippet or reference will be highly helpful

Regards